# How to exit a Generic list ForEach with delegate?

Tags: generics, list, foreach, delegates

How do i exit a Generic list ForEach with a delegate? Break or return doesn't work.

Example:

```
        Peoples.ForEach(delegate(People someone)
        {
            if(someone.Name == "foo")
               ???? What to do to exit immediatly ?
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot achieve this with [ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

just write it out like this

```
foreach(People someone in Peoples)
{
    if(someone.Name == "foo") break;
    // rest of code below for != "foo"...
}
```

to just skip foo and still do the action for everyone else you could do

```
if(someone.Name == "foo") continue;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
        Peoples.TakeWhile(p=> p.Name != "foo")
            .ToList().ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine(p.Name));
```

but that's overkill and bad in terms of performance ...

Just use a simple `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

While not recommended you can throw an exception from inside the `ForEach()` when the condition is satisfied.

Comment: Costly though. Exceptions are not part of normal behaviour of a program, the clue is in the name. :)